# Can't install inkscape on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, inkscape

I tried to install inkscape in my Ubuntu 14, but it doesn't exist. And when I install my ubuntu says that is already install, but when I put in the terminal $ inkscape it says that is necessary to install.

It is confusion.

See file below

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: *Please* don't post screenshots of terminal output: just paste the text. And you can paste in English by prepending `LC_ALL=C` to your commands...

Comment: first of, if you use `-y` (which just makes apt-get assume that you agree with installing the suggested package), set the flag after install and before to-be-installed packages. Second try to `sudo apt-get update` , then `sudo apt-get install inkscape`

Comment: What happens if you type `which inkscape`? Do you see it in the Applications menu?

Comment: See this blog post, it shows how to add the Inkscape PPA: http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-latest-version-inkscape-in-ubuntu-14-04-or-linux-mint-17-via-ppa.html

Comment: cross posted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/487360/cant-install-inkscape-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry but I can't read your language.

It is possible that you forgot to add the PPA of inkscape:

1. Add inkscape.dev/stable PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
   ```
2. Update list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. install inkscape

   ```
   sudo apt-get install inkscape
   ```

Source: [How to install latest Version Inkscape In Ubuntu 14.04 or Linux Mint 17 Via PPA](http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-latest-version-inkscape-in-ubuntu-14-04-or-linux-mint-17-via-ppa.html)

Comment: `inkscape` is in the default repositories of ubuntu, it's not necessary to add PPA for this.

Comment: The Inkscape snap is newer than the version in the archive and works on all supported Ubuntu versions, including 14.04. 

Execute `sudo apt install snapd` in a terminal to install snapd and then `sudo snap install inkscape` to install the Inkscape snap.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you had inkscape installed at some point, and then some files got deleted?

In 14.04, inkscape is included in the main repository:

```
$ apt-cache policy inkscape
inkscape:
Installed: 0.48.4-3ubuntu2
Candidate: 0.48.4-3ubuntu2
Version table:
*** 0.48.4-3ubuntu2 0
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

What happens if you do the following?:

```
$ apt-get update; apt-get install --reinstall inkscape
```